# SSIS nsoftware SFTPSend task is failing when I move to the production server

Tags: ssis, sftp, sql-server-data-tools

My SSIS package is running fine from my local dev environment, but when I move to production it fails saying:

*nsoftware SFTPSend Task (v20):Error: Error validating property SSHPassword: You must specify a value for Password or Keyboard-Interactive authentication.*

I'm running visual studio 2015 and sql server 2016.

Any idea why it is losing the SSHPassword value when I build to prod?

Comment: I'm guessing that SSHPassword is a "sensitive" value, which means that it is stripped out when you migrate the package. You need to parameterise it and supply it at runtime.

Comment: Here's a guide on how to do it, assuming this is the issue. https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004561373-How-to-run-an-SSIS-package-with-sensitive-data-on-SQL-Server

Comment: thanks, setting up the Parameterize option for that property on the component did the trick

Comment: If you have time, please add an answer and explain what you did to help others.

Comment: (and you should be able to accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to right click on the SFTPSend task and click Parameterize. Then I created a new parameter and mapped it to the SSHPassword property. I also marked my parameter as Sensitive so that it's not in clear text.

Here's a guide https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004561373-How-to-run-an-SSIS-package-with-sensitive-data-on-SQL-Server courtesy of Nick